# Why doesn't my image width inherit from parent div width

Tags: html, css

Guys I have a div like this:

```
<div id="image-container">
 <img id="image" src="#" > //with an image inside
</div>
```

And styled this way:

```
#image-container {
    width: 750px;
    height: 360px !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

But when i load the page, and inspect element on the image to know its dimensions, this is what it says:

```
element.style {
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Why doesnt the image inherit the width of the div? And I cant manually put the desired width of the image for some reason, so I cant do this:

```
#image {
 width : 330px; //manually putting width
 height: 303px; //same same which i cannot do this for some reason
}
```

Any idea why or how to solve this?

I all tried the solution below:

and here is what i get from inspect element:

```
#image {
    height: inherit; // crossed-out
    width: inherit; // crossed-out
}
```

Something is overwriting my image dimensions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9PmPC/)

```
#image-container {
    width: 750px;
    height: 360px !important;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#image-container img{ 
    width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
#image-container img { 
    width: inherit;
}
```

fiddle : [about inheriting width](http://jsfiddle.net/Holybreath/96vb8/)

Answer (score 4):

You should set your image's `width` and `height` properties to either `100%`, `inherit` or the same values so it completely fills the space of the parent.

```
#Container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#Image {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
}
```

You can check this on [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3U3Ej/1/). Also, make shure no other CSS is being loaded on the document.

Answer (score 3):

(In case I forgot how)

I'm using bootstrap 3. I have a column which has a width of 768px. My markup look this:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <img src="path/to/image.png" />
</div>
```

setting the width to 100% will cause other images (especially those have small width) to blur. So my solution is use the `max-width` property:

```
// parent div's width is currently 768px.
img { max-width: 100% }
```

So the other images (have small width)  will use their exact width.

Answer (score 0):

```
#image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Would suffice