# Does img inherit parent element dimensions?

Tags: html, css

In the below code,

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="visa">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Visa.svg/175px-Visa.svg.png"> VISA
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="amex">
            <img src="http://www.hoax-slayer.com/images/american-express-security-update-scam-2.jpg"> AMEX
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="cardtype" value="mastercard">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b7/MasterCard_Logo.svg/2000px-MasterCard_Logo.svg.png"> Master card
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`input` element in `td` is inheriting the width unlike `img`. why?

Does `img` element inherit parent element(`td`) height and width?
[Here](https://github.com/shamhub/FrontEndDev/blob/master/acadgild/assignments/session3/assignment3/file.html) is the complete code.

Comment: no img element doesn't inherit parent height and width in your css code. if you want. you should put css property inherit like this {width: inherit;}

Comment: @happenask Sorry, I did not get you. In my code this is inheritance hierarchy `form`<-`div`<-`table`<-`tr`<-`td`<-`img`. Am I correct? I already set the size of `form` to `400px`. `input` element in `td` is inheriting the `width` unlike `img`. why?

Comment: I mean that if you want to make img element  inherit width and height from parent element . you should specify css property inherit. ex) img{width: inherit;height:inherit}

Comment: @happenask  After inheriting, I still see the same problem

Comment: What is your intention here? Do you want the img to take the available width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some styles, like font family, text-alignment are automatically inherited by child elements from their parent element .Others are not automatically inherited
.In this case, you have to set width and height to parent and then specify inherit property in css code

try below code

```
     table {
            width:100%;
        }
        td{
            width: 30%;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
```

after that 
you have to specify inherit property

```
img {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: But, how can I set `td` with fixed size(`100px`)? Because their parent/ancestor are following percentage rule for responsive design

Comment: So, when you inherit in percentages, one has explicitly mention the width for every child element?

Comment: Some styles, like font family, text-alignment  are automatically inherited by child elements from their parent element .Others are not automatically inherited.

Comment: Did you get the chance to go thru this [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/303241/query-on-responsive-imaging)? This is related to same code

Answer (score 4):

> By default the `<img>` element does not inherit height and width of
>   parent tag. You need to externally specify this in your custom css
>   like:

```
img {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```

This thread should help you to understand it better: [Why doesn't my image width inherit from parent div width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030326/why-doesnt-my-image-width-inherit-from-parent-div-width)

In your case you have to make sure that the right css is applied to your parent node.

Comment: ya but after this changes, I still see the same problem.

Comment: @overexchange have you set a width to your `td`. If you haven't done that then the image doesn't have a width to inherit and will just take up it's original width. [JsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/pok44n6a/)

Comment: @NatalieHedström `table, tr, td{ max-width: 100%; max-height: 60%;}` these elements are child of `div` that has `width: 90%` of `form` element.  Please see the output of my code.

Comment: @overexchange In the CSS you provided you do not specify the width of the `td`. Hence the image tag does not know which width to inherit.
If you look at my JsFiddle I specified a width of `100px` to the td. This means that the image element will inherit a width of `100px`. I could specify a width of `33%`, this means that the image element would occupy `33%` of it's parents width.

Comment: @NatalieHedström I specified width of `td` as `max-width: 100%;`. Please check the code at line 44. Understood that `img{width:inherit}` would not inherit. But specifying fixed width to `td` spoils the responsive design using percentage rules. BTW, `img{ width: 10%; height: 10%;}` is working

Comment: @overexchange `max-width` is **not** the same as `width` and in this case you're inheriting the width. With a max-width of 100% you're only saying the the `td` is not allowed to be bigger than the full width of your table. Like I said in my comment you need to specify a width for each `td` (i.e. 100px).

Answer (score 1):

As Bikram Kundu mentioned, `img` does not inherit the height and width of its parent by default. It takes its original dimension determined by its content. You need to specify the width and height explicitly for the image to have the desired dimensions.

I think your intention is to restrict image to its container. You can use `width:100%` on the image for this purpose

```
table img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: am not sure, why we are discussing about `width:inherit`. I never used before.